# Using rmdir() and RemoveDirectory() can a deleted file be recovered?

Tags: php, windows, rmdir

If you use a code like below to delete a file that was created by your code, where does that file get deleted too? Can the file be recovered?

```
function RemoveDirectory($path){    

foreach(glob("{$path}/*") as $file)
    {
        if(is_dir($file)) { 
        RemoveDirectory($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($path);
}
```

Let's just say I called this directory at the wrong time in the code, and I have regrets.

Comment: Did you check the bin?

Comment: it might be possible to undelete at the filesystem level using dedicated tools, provided you don't wait too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file gets [deleted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_deletion) from your hard drive. It doesn't get removed to a "Recycle Bin". It gets completely removed. To recover the file after that, you will need some sort of undelete software, which may or may not work, depending on whether or not you have overwritten those sectors of the hard drive with other files since the delete took place. If you accidentally delete a file, remove the drive immediately and boot from a different drive to prevent further writes from occurring.

Comment: ...or could be recovered from a backup, should daily backups be an activated option on their service.

Comment: Backup is the route I'm taking, this is a hard learned lesson on programing in safeguards :)